# Yarn Install - Not recognized as command in Windows 11 Powershell

Tags: powershell, yarnpkg

Yarn's not recognized as a cmd command.

I tried installing it globally with 'npm install -g yarn' and adding a path variable to "C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn".
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

First thing first, you should check you have 16+ node.js installed and, you can check it with

1. `node -v`
   If it's valid,
2. run the `npm config get prefix` it'll give you a path CTRL+C this path
3. Open the start search and type in env and then click "Edit the system environment variables"
4. Modify the Environment variables
5. Add the copied path to you PATH as new[image]

After this you should be good, but if the PS is cannot load the Yarn run this command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a few things you can try:

1. You may need to close and reopen the Powershell windows because newly added environment variables or updates to them are not automatically reflected to already open shell windows.
2. Check if your path is correct: it normally is `C:\Users\endo\AppData\Roaming\npm` on my PC, not `C:\Users\endo\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn` as you mentioned.
3. Try running `yarn.cmd` or `yarn.ps1`.
4. Try CMD instead of Powershell, see if it works that way.